# Camera Image not displaying in ImageView

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to display a captured image from a Camera Intent inside an ImageView. I am able to get the camera to open and make a directory for the image, but when I pass the image through the intent and attempt to call it, the image is not displayed. This is what I am doing:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private ImageView addPicture;
private Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(//setting the view);

    addPicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
            imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
            File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_001.jpg");
            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
            startActivityForResult(imageIntent, 0);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    addPicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilepicture_registerone);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                addPicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                stream.close();


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }

            RoundImage image = new RoundImage(bitmap);

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bad Image Request. Please Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

My Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

And My ImageView in XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/profilepicture_registerone"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="addPicture" />
```

**EDIT: I had the incorrect IDs due to me attempting to change things for this post. I changed them back to the original ID to avoid any more confusion.**

**EDIT 2: After further testing, I've found that no Images are being set inside of the `onActivityResult()` method. I tried loading a drawable image and that did not work either. It worked when I called it inside of `onCreate()`.**

Comment: found the solution ? @solomon Powell

Comment: @Mano unforunately, no. I even tried loading a stock image from my drawable folder as an image file inside of `onActivityResult()` and that does not work either. Which is strange, as the OnActivityResults is being called.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30977539/4447803 ,try this code  any doubt ask me-it will work both gallery and camera with crop.

Comment: create your imageview inside Oncreate don,t put inside OnActivvty result

Answer (score 1):

You need to find your ImageView ID in `onCreate()` with proper ID tag.

```
 addPicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilepicture_registerone);
```

**And**

Please check your bitmap, is it null or not?

Comment: I changed some things for the sake of this post. I'll edit that in the post, but the error still occurs even with the correct IDs

Comment: I found that the `data.getData()` method is returning null and throws a NullPointerException when being tested if null or not.

Comment: Your file is created in SD Card?

Comment: Yes, the Image gets stored on the SD card

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,

**Declare the constant in Class area:**

```
final int TAKE_PHOTO_REQ = 100;
```

**Invoke Camera Intent:**

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_REQ);
```

**Add onActivityResult(..) to your Activity**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case TAKE_PHOTO_REQ: {
            if (resultCode == TakePicture.RESULT_OK && data != null) {

                Bitmap myBmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");



                imageView.setImageBitmap(myBmp);
                break;
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

*Still having problem then check your **ImageView** ,if it is correct or not.

Hope this will be helpful ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, you are using the correct id for your imageview. In the code, the id in the xml is "picture" but you refer to profilepicture_registerone in java ?

Comment: I changed some things for the sake of this post and forgot to change all of them. I've reverted them due to that, but the error still occurs even with the correct IDs

Comment: Is the image getting saved on the phone, Are you able to view the image using other apps ?

Comment: Yes. The image gets saved as "image_001.jpg" inside of the folder "MyImages".

Comment: Try using bundle to pass the image, It is possible that the image passed through the intent right now is null