# Unable to define onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

Tags: android

I am trying to select image from gallery in my app and for that I have written the code to pick image from gallery. But when I try to define the `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` I am getting the error

> onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) in
>   com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample clashes with  onActivityResult(int
>   requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) in android.app.Fragment

How should I define `onActivityResult`. 
Here is the code snippet

```
public class MyAccount extends Fragment {
    private Button button;
    private Button button1;
    private Button remove;
    private Button change;
    private EditText editName;
    private EditText editGender;
    private EditText editAge;
    private EditText editCountry;
    private EditText editDesccription;
    private EditText editSports;
    private EditText editFood;
    private String apikey;
    private ImageView add;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    String val = null, imgpath=null;
    // Session Manager Class
    SessionManager session;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // Session class instance
        session = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        // get user data from session
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();


        // apikey
        apikey = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_api);

        final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_account_a, null);
        button = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.account);
        button1 = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.profile);
        remove = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.remove);
        change = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.change);
        editName = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.editName);
        editGender = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.editGender);
        editAge = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.editAge);
        editCountry = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.editCountry);
        editDesccription = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.editDescription);
        editFood = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.editFood);
        editSports = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.editSports);
        add = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.add);

        // create bitmap from resource
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.profile_blank_xlarge);

        // set circle bitmap
        ImageView mImage = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
        mImage.setImageBitmap(getCircleBitmap(bm));
        mImage.setTag("profile_blank_xlarge");

        new FetchOperation().execute();

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    post();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

            if(!mImage.getTag().equals("profile_blank_xlarge")) {
                remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                              @Override
                                              public void onClick(View v) {
                                                  remove_image();
                                              }
                                          }

                );
            }
        else
            {
                remove.setEnabled(false);
            }
        change.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onClick(View v) {
                                          change_image();
                                      }
                                  }

        );

        return layout;
    }

    //Functions for profile image



    private Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        final Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = Color.RED;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        bitmap.recycle();

        return output;
    }

    // Function to remove Image
    public void remove_image()
    {

        // create bitmap from resource
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_portrait);

        // set circle bitmap
        ImageView mImage = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.image);
        mImage.setImageBitmap(getCircleBitmap(bm));
        mImage.setTag("profile_blank_xlarge");

    }

    //Function to change image
    public  void  change_image()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

    }



    //Want to define onActivityResult here
```

Comment: The error says you have clashes in the method. Can you pst some code of your activity / fragment?

Comment: @RoiDivon have added the code snippet

Comment: Have you put the `@Override`?

Comment: BTW: you may want to read some things about code style, esp. naming classes/methods convention in Java: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30977539/4447803 try this link,

Answer (score 1):

If you just call `startActivityForResult()` function, that will invoke the `startActivityForResult()` function of `Fragment` since you are calling from it.

So you need to override the `onActivityResult()` in the fragment to receive its callback.

If you need the callback in the activity, then you need to call like

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult()
```