# Android Camera Intent crashes with Android L

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-5.0-lollipop

My app is working properly on all api till Kitkat but it's not working in lollipop. The moment i clicks for capturing a photo using camera in my app, it crashes.

```
cam.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });
```

---

This is my onActivityResult()

```
    case CAMERA_REQUEST: {

    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);
    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
    String imageType = options.outMimeType;
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,200,100);//512 and 256 whatever you want as scale
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath,options);

    File pngDir = new   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"PicUploadTemp");
    if (!pngDir.exists()) {
        pngDir.mkdirs();
        }

  File pngfile = new File(pngDir,"texture1.jpg");
    FileOutputStream fOut;

    try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(pngfile);

             yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50,fOut);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pngfile.getPath().toString());
    rlLayout.setBackground(d);

    yourSelectedImage.recycle();
//    resizedBitmap.recycle();

    xfile = pngfile; 
}
break;
```

I want to compress the image and this above code is working amazingly for gingerbread, ICS , kitkat but not for Android L

I am getting null pointer Exception

Please suggest me some solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30977539/4447803 try this link it will work in lollipop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot really say anything about this without the logcat output, It may be becoming null in as a result of you using on of the deprecated method in the BitmapFacotry class.

Define these globally in your activity,

```
   Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
             android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

   private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
```

in button click call your camera intent like this

```
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

make sure to use

```
           @Override
           public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
             super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
           }
```

use this to retrieve photo

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {

        //get photo
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

     }
```

Comment: Thanks , resolved my issue by combining ur solution with other blog's sol